# Count words Scala and create a dictionnary

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a csv file with a type and a description text

```
type ; text
  0  ; hello world
  0  ; hello text 2
  1  ; text1
  1  ; text
  2  ; world base
  2  ; Hey you
  2  ; test
```

In fact, I want to create a dictionnary and have another csv file structured like this with a unique line of each type and the frequence of each word on the description

```
type ; hello ; world ; text ; 2 ; text1 ; base ; hey ; you ; test
  0  ;  2    ;  1    ;  1   ; 1 ;   0   ;   0  ;  0  ;  0  ;   0
  1  ;  0    ;  0    ;  1   ; 0 ;   1   ;   0  ;  0  ;  0  ;   0
  2  ;  0    ;  1    ;  0   ; 0 ;   0   ;   1  ;  1  ;  1  ;   1
```

I have tons of lines on my csv file with many Strings, this is just an example.

I am just starting to work with spark and scala these days. Any help is needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("text", explode(split($"text", "\\s+")))
  .groupBy("type")
  .pivot("text")
  .count.na.fill(0)
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer - good answers attempt to explain how the solution addresses the original problem.